# ASP.NET Identity, CookieAuth Login Path - broken on dev machine

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-identity

LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login")

This works fine on production - but because I am using full IIS on the dev machine - not IIS Express (I have lots of issues with express) - the path can't be found, and tilda ~ paths aren't allowed for some bizarre reason.

How can I set a login path that will work on both my dev and production servers?

I can find nothing on this on Google,

Comment: Why you don't introduce this in web.config file?

Comment: How would i do that? Basically I need http://localhost/myapp/account/login - to map to the same place locally as http://myapp.com/account/login map to in production.

Answer (score 0):

Create an entry in your hosts file for `myapp.local` to point to 127.0.0.1. When you configure your local IIS add a binding to your app so you can use `http://myapp.local` during development. This way you'll have the same paths locally and in production.

Comment: hmm this is a huge fail - it should support ~/ paths.

Comment: @niico fail or not - that is why you get this behaviour

Comment: yes but this problem has been overcome in most moderns asp.net apps by using tilda ~ paths - I don't understand why this doesn't support them.